# `cardano-tracer`: `VersionMismatch` error during handshake

Tags: cardano-node

Good day. I'm trying to see how `cardano-tracer` works in depth and for tests I'm trying to connect it to the node created by `cardano-testnet`, but getting this error:

```
"cardano-tracer, connection with \"/tmp/nix-shell.rnSoi4/testnet-test-21056d614f5c271d/socket/node-spo1\" failed: HandshakeError (VersionMismatch [] [32777,32778,32779,32780,32781,32782,32783,32784])"
```

I'm building everything from sources with Nix from the tag [8.7.3](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-node/releases/tag/8.7.3).

Then using this command to start testnet:

```
cabal run cardano-testnet -- cardano --babbage-era --testnet-magic 1234
```

After network is up, I'm following [Local Scenario part of the dicumentation](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-node/blob/master/cardano-tracer/docs/cardano-tracer.md#local-scenario) with `ConnectTo` option.

Config looks something like this:

```yaml
{  
  "networkMagic": 1234,
  "network": {
    "tag": "ConnectTo",
    "contents": [
      "/tmp/nix-shell.rnSoi4/testnet-test-21056d614f5c271d/socket/node-spo1"
    ]
  },
  "logging": [
    {
      "logRoot": "/path/to/tracer-logs",
      "logMode": "FileMode",
      "logFormat": "ForMachine"
    }
  ],
  "rotation": {
    "rpFrequencySecs": 15,
    "rpKeepFilesNum": 5,
    "rpLogLimitBytes": 5000,
    "rpMaxAgeHours": 1
  }
}
```

Then I start tracer with

```
cabal run cardano-tracer -- -c /path/to/active-tracer-config.json
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.411851532Z","ns":"Tracer.ParamsAre","data":{"ConfigPath":"/path/to/active-tracer-config.json","MinLogSeverity":null,"StateDir":null,"kind":"TracerParamsAre"},"sev":"Info","thread":"4","host":"Omen"}
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.412203051Z","ns":"Tracer.ConfigIs","data":{"Config":{"ekgRequestFreq":null,"hasEKG":null,"hasForwarding":null,"hasPrometheus":null,"hasRTView":null,"loRequestNum":null,"logging":[{"logFormat":"ForMachine","logMode":"FileMode","logRoot":"/path/to/tracer-logs"}],"metricsComp":null,"network":{"contents":["/tmp/nix-shell.rnSoi4/testnet-test-21056d614f5c271d/socket/node-spo1"],"tag":"ConnectTo"},"networkMagic":1234,"rotation":{"rpFrequencySecs":15,"rpKeepFilesNum":5,"rpLogLimitBytes":5000,"rpMaxAgeHours":1},"verbosity":null},"kind":"TracerConfigIs"},"sev":"Info","thread":"4","host":"Omen"}
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.412205245Z","ns":"Tracer.InitStart","data":{"kind":"TracerInitStarted"},"sev":"Info","thread":"4","host":"Omen"}
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.4122078Z","ns":"Tracer.EventQueues","data":{"kind":"TracerInitEventQueues"},"sev":"Info","thread":"4","host":"Omen"}
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.412443698Z","ns":"Tracer.InitDone","data":{"kind":"TracerInitDone"},"sev":"Info","thread":"4","host":"Omen"}
{"at":"2024-01-29T08:00:15.413581843Z","ns":"Tracer.StartedLogRotator","data":{"kind":"TracerStartedLogRotator"},"sev":"Info","thread":"7","host":"Omen"}
"cardano-tracer, connection with \"/tmp/nix-shell.rnSoi4/testnet-test-21056d614f5c271d/socket/node-spo1\" failed: HandshakeError (VersionMismatch [] [32777,32778,32779,32780,32781,32782,32783,32784])"
```

What could be wrong here?

From [RTView docs](https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-node/blob/master/cardano-tracer/docs/cardano-rtview.md) it looks like node need to be run with `--tracer-socket-path-accept` option maybe? Is there a way to set this for `cardano-testnet` node?

Comment: Manage to make it work in `AcceptAt` mode with preprod node, where node initiates prortocol, but `ConnectTo` still throws an error during handshake